# testNG XML file not consider my second class its run only my first class and on second its showing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

When I run my XML first class is running. first class contains `@beforeTest` And `@AfterTest` annotation. My `@Test` annotation is in second class but it's not running.

```
<suite name = "smsweb"> 
    <test name = "login">
        <classes>
            <class name = "testNG.datapro" /> //Running
        </classes>
    </test> 
    <test name = "form">
        <classes>           
            <class name = "testNG.assetscat" /> //not running
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

--1st class "datapro"

```
package testNG;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

public class datapro {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void webopen() throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\saad bin usman\\Downloads\\Compressed\\chromedriver_win32_2\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Actions a = new Actions(driver);
        driver.get("http://test.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        SoftAssert softassert = new SoftAssert();

        String title = driver.getTitle();
        String exptitle = "Cloud Tenants - Sales Management System";

        String user = "admin";
        String pass = "admin";

        Assert.assertEquals(title, exptitle);

        String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtUsername']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtUsername']")).sendKeys(user);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtPassword']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtPassword']")).sendKeys(pass);

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='section-login']/div/div/div[4]/button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        String expectedurl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        Assert.assertNotEquals(url, expectedurl);

        String formname = "asset group";
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='sidebar-toggler hidden-phone']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtMenuSearch']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtMenuSearch']")).sendKeys(formname);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement searcharea = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//ul[@class='page-sidebar-menu']"));
        WebElement abc = searcharea.findElement(By.tagName("ul"));
        List<WebElement> xyz = abc.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

        System.out.println("No of Count Related Your Search " + xyz.size());
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < xyz.size(); i++) {
            if (formname.equalsIgnoreCase(xyz.get(i).getText())) {
                System.out.println("Form Name Which System Open " + xyz.get(i).getText());
                count++;
                xyz.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count < 1) {
        }

        WebElement formpagename = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='portlet-title']/div[@class='caption span6 text-left']"));
        softassert.assertEquals(formpagename.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(formpagename.getText()),
                formname.equalsIgnoreCase(formpagename.getText()));

        Thread.sleep(5000L);
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnAddRecord']/i")).click();
            softassert.assertEquals(formpagename.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(formpagename.getText()),
                    formpagename.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(formpagename.getText()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Add New Record's Button Not Found");
        }
        softassert.assertAll();
        Thread.sleep(8000L);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void closebrowser() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

--2nd Class "assetscat"

```
package testNG;

import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

public class assetscat {

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void entername() throws InterruptedException {
        datapro d = new datapro();
        SoftAssert sa = new SoftAssert();

        d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnAddEditSave']")).click();
        d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='icon-remove-circle']")).click();

        System.out.println(d.driver
                .findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='frmAddEdit']//div[@class='control-group required error']")).getText());

        // WebElement notisyb
        // =d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='errorNotificationBtn']"));
        // System.out.println(notisyb.getText());

        List<WebElement> errorelement = d.driver.findElements(By.xpath(
                ".//*[@id='frmAddEdit']//div[@class='control-group required error']/div/*[@data-dbpropertyname]"));
        System.out.println("Mendatory Fields are ");
        for (int er = 0; er < errorelement.size(); er++) {
            System.out.println(errorelement.get(er).getAttribute("data-dbpropertyname"));
        }
        for (int e = 0; e < errorelement.size(); e++) {

            // System.out.println(errorelement.get(e).getAttribute("data-dbpropertyname"));

            if (errorelement.get(e).getAttribute("data-dbpropertyname").equalsIgnoreCase("Name")) {

                WebElement savebut = d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnAddEditSave']"));

                errorelement.get(e).sendKeys("         ");
                savebut.click();
                WebElement notipannel = d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='icon-remove-circle']"));
                if (notipannel.isDisplayed()) {
                    notipannel.click();
                }

                List<WebElement> cond1 = d.driver.findElements(By.xpath(
                        ".//*[@id='frmAddEdit']//div[@class='control-group required error']/div/*[@data-dbpropertyname]"));

                sa.assertEquals(errorelement.size(), cond1.size());

                errorelement.get(e).clear();
                errorelement.get(e).sendKeys("@#$%^");
                savebut.click();
                if (notipannel.isDisplayed()) {
                    notipannel.click();
                }

                List<WebElement> cond2 = d.driver.findElements(By.xpath(
                        ".//*[@id='frmAddEdit']//div[@class='control-group required error']/div/*[@data-dbpropertyname]"));

                sa.assertEquals(errorelement.size(), cond2.size());

                errorelement.get(e).clear();
                errorelement.get(e).sendKeys("CHaracter20000CHaracter20000CHaracter20000CHaracter20000CHaracter20000");
                savebut.click();
                if (notipannel.isDisplayed()) {
                    notipannel.click();
                }

                List<WebElement> cond3 = d.driver.findElements(By.xpath(
                        ".//*[@id='frmAddEdit']//div[@class='control-group required error']/div/*[@data-dbpropertyname]"));

                sa.assertEquals(errorelement.size(), cond3.size());
                sa.assertAll();

                if (notipannel.isDisplayed()) {
                    notipannel.click();
                }
                try {
                    WebElement datasave = d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='notification alert-success']"));
                    if (datasave.isDisplayed()) {
                        System.out.println("Afetr Enter " + errorelement.get(e).getAttribute("data-dbpropertyname")
                                + " Transaction Sucussfully Saved");
                        break;

                    }
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    System.out.println("After Enter " + errorelement.get(e).getAttribute("data-dbpropertyname")
                            + " Transaction not Saved");
                }

            }

            else if (errorelement.get(e).getAttribute("data-dbpropertyname").equalsIgnoreCase("ShortName")) {
                errorelement.get(e).clear();
                errorelement.get(e).sendKeys("Sadi");
                d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnAddEditSave']")).click();

                WebElement notipannel = d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='icon-remove-circle']"));
                if (notipannel.isDisplayed()) {
                    notipannel.click();
                }
                try {
                    WebElement datasave = d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='notification alert-success']"));
                    if (datasave.isDisplayed()) {
                        System.out.println("Afetr Enter " + errorelement.get(e).getAttribute("data-dbpropertyname")
                                + " Transaction Sucussfully Saved");
                        break;

                    }
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    System.out.println("After Enter " + errorelement.get(e).getAttribute("data-dbpropertyname")
                            + " Transaction not Saved");
                }

            }

            else if (errorelement.get(e).getAttribute("data-dbpropertyname").equalsIgnoreCase("Colorcode")) {

                errorelement.get(e).sendKeys("Black");
                d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnAddEditSave']")).click();

                WebElement notipannel = d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='icon-remove-circle']"));
                if (notipannel.isDisplayed()) {
                    notipannel.click();
                }
                try {
                    WebElement datasave = d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='notification alert-success']"));
                    if (datasave.isDisplayed()) {
                        System.out.println("Afetr Enter " + errorelement.get(e).getAttribute("data-dbpropertyname")
                                + " Transaction Sucussfully Saved");
                        break;

                    }
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    System.out.println("After Enter " + errorelement.get(e).getAttribute("data-dbpropertyname")
                            + " Transaction not Saved");
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNG guarantees that a `@BeforeTest` annotated method gets executed only once per `<test>` tag. You haven't shown us your test code. But going by your description I am guessing that both of your test classes have `@Test` methods that depend on a variable which is expected to be initialised via a `@BeforeTest` method and this `@BeforeTest` method is perhaps part of some common base class.

If your use case absolutely needs the initialisation to be done only once per `<test>` then you might want to do the following :

Move the initialisation logic as part of either

- org.testng.ITestListener – If you would like the setup to be executed only once per test tag ( i.e., instead of using @BeforeTest)
- org.testng.ISuiteListener – If you would like the setup to be executed only once per suite tag ( i.e., instead of using @BeforeSuite)
- Use the setAttribute() method to persist the initialised data as an attribute of either the ITestContext (this represents a test tag ) or ISuite (this represents a suite tag).
- Wire in this listener into TestNG via :

  - the listeners tag (or)
  - the @Listeners annotation (or)
  - Service loaders.

You can refer to [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2017/09/25/running-setup-only-once-per-testsuite-without-using-beforesuitebeforetest/) blog post of mine to get more details and also for some samples that shows all of this.

**UPDATE AFTER SEEING THE SOURCE CODE**

You have completely got this wrong. There's a difference between you instantiating a class and TestNG instantiating a class. The reason why your `assetscat.entername()` fails with a `NullPointerException` when accessing the webdriver data member is because all of the initialisation is being done in `webopen()` which is annotated with `@BeforeTest`.

To fix the problem you have two options :

1. Explicitly invoke the method `webopen()` in your `assetscat.entername()` method before trying to access the `driver` object in it.
2. Have `assetscat extends datapro`.

I would also recommend that you spend sometime working with all these annotations to get a better understanding of how to use them.

Comment: thanks brother for your concern. My first class consist two annotations these are atbeforeTest and atAfterTest and my second class contain only atTest annotation when i run my XML file only my first class running when i paste atTest Class in first class it works and bro how can i send you code of my both classes ?

Comment: You still arent showing us what your class looks like. Without that, its hard to say.

Comment: added both classes.

Comment: brother can u plz tell me how can i explicitly invoke webopen() in asserscat.entername(). just syntax .

Comment: You just do `d.webopen()`. Not sure what the question is. Please accept my answer if it resolved your query.

Comment: Sir i used this
  datapro data = new datapro();
  data.webopen();
so datapro class run twice .. but assetscat class working :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work.

```
<suite name = "smsweb"> 
    <test name = "login">
        <classes>
            <class name = "testNG.datapro" /> 
        </classes>
        <classes>           
            <class name = "testNG.assetscat" /> 
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

Comment: now 1st one also not running. :( when i run suite it shows error and failed.

Comment: even i tried this but its also not working. its run only first class i.e. "testNG.datapro"  

 <suite name = "smsweb">
 <test name = "login">
  <classes>
   <class name = "testNG.datapro" />
   <class name = "testNG.assetscat" /> 
  </classes>
 </test> 
</suite>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ,this will make both the tests running

```
<suite name = "smsweb"> 
    <test name = "login">
        <classes>

            <class name = "testNG.datapro" />  

            <class name = "testNG.assetscat" />
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

Comment: i already tried but its not working. its only run "testNG.datapro" .